# Parse .NET Core configuration and modify the binding

Tags: azure, .net-core, config

I am building an Azure Function App that requires some initial configuration for it to work.
The values portion of local.settings.json contains a key-value pair of the properties as follows:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyConfiguration:AllowedEmailDomains":  "gmail.com,hotmail.com"
  }
}
```

My configuration class looks as follows:

```
    public class MyConfiguration
    {
        public List<string> AllowedEmailDomains { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

and I bind it as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<MyConfiguration>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration").Bind(settings);
            });
```

Obviously, currently, the value binds as a list with a single string element.

This means that I could do something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<MyConfiguration>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration").Bind(settings);
                if (settings.AllowedEmailDomains != null) {
                     // split the string and update the property.
                }
            });
```

I know that I can provide the values for the list in the App configuration. However, I prefer to have a single long string, which I split by myself, so the user doesn't need to provide loads of these settings, and can stick to one fields within the app configuration.

Is there a better way of doing this, so I could read the settings and straightaway cast to List?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Singleton for your configurations.

```
public static class GenericSingleton<T> where T : class
{
    static volatile T _instance;
    static object _lock = new object();

    static GenericSingleton()
    {
    }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        ConstructorInfo constructor = null;

                        try
                        {
                            // Binding flags exclude generic constructors.
                            constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[0], null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            throw new SingletonException(exception.Message);
                        }

                        if (constructor == null || constructor.IsAssembly)
                            // Also exclude internal renderers.
                            throw new SingletonException(string.Format("A private or protected constructor is missing for '{0}'.", typeof(T).Name));

                        _instance = (T)constructor.Invoke(null);
                    }
                }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Create base configuration:

```
public class BaseAppConfiguration
{
    internal static BaseAppConfiguration BaseConfig => GenericSingleton<BaseAppConfiguration>.Instance;
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot ConfigurationRoot = null;

    public BaseAppConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        ConfigurationRoot = builder.Build();
    }

    public RedisConfigurationSection RedisTokenConfig()
    {
        return
            new RedisConfigurationSection()
            {
                Host = ConfigurationRoot["RedisTokenConfiguration:host"],
                Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationRoot["RedisTokenConfiguration:port"]),
                Password = ConfigurationRoot["RedisTokenConfiguration:password"],
                DatabaseID = int.Parse(ConfigurationRoot["RedisTokenConfiguration:databaseID"])
            };
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationRoot.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
    }

    public string GetDatabaseProvider()
    {
        return ConfigurationRoot.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("Provider").Value;
    }

    public string GetAppVersion()
    {
        return ConfigurationRoot.GetSection("Version").Value;
    }

    public EMailConfigurationSection GetEmailConfig()
    {
        return
            new EMailConfigurationSection()
            {
                SmtpServer = ConfigurationRoot["EmailConfiguration:smtpServer"],
                SmtpPort = int.Parse(ConfigurationRoot["EmailConfiguration:smtpPort"]),
                Username = ConfigurationRoot["EmailConfiguration:username"],
                Password = ConfigurationRoot["EmailConfiguration:password"]
            };
    }
}
```

And create your additional configuration for each application:

```
public class ExampleAppConfiguration : BaseAppConfiguration
{
    public ExampleAppConfiguration()
    {

    }
    public static ExampleAppConfiguration Config => GenericSingleton<ExampleAppConfiguration>.Instance;
}
```